# How to find whether a column with lots of words has a genuine email id or not in Apache Pig?

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I've a column which has paragraphs in it. It is a 10000 rows column wherein I need to find which column has genuine email id. I've used `columnname matches '(.*)@(.*).(.*)'`, which also gave me outputs like `'@nelson' '.... @kumar...'` etc which I don't need. I only need a genuine email id. Please let me know how to find this in such huge paragraphs using Apache Pig code.

Answer (score 0):

Since PIG uses Java regular expression [form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) you can use something like this which will cover most cases.

```
columnname matches '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$'
```

If you want more expressions, a simple "java email validation regex" search should provide you with a plethora of expressions to validate the email addresses.